# Referrer in access.log is a directory

Tags: security, web-crawler, logging

It seems that the referrer on the following log is a folder.

```
112.200.208.5 - - [29/Jul/2013:20:43:14 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/pos-code.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 294677 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
61.3.158.113 - - [29/Jul/2013:20:43:14 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/lnosKHEN/payroll_system_-_lnoskhen_0.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 10806 "http://www.mysite.com/download-code" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0.472.25 Safari/534.3"
112.200.208.5 - - [29/Jul/2013:20:43:15 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/pos-code.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 21465 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
112.200.208.5 - - [29/Jul/2013:20:43:16 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/pos-code.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 469304 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
112.200.208.5 - - [29/Jul/2013:20:43:17 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/pos-code.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 238639 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
112.200.208.5 - - [29/Jul/2013:20:43:18 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/pos-code.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 267724 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
39.41.211.234 - - [29/Jul/2013:20:43:22 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/john.lemar/zest-project.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 23361 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/john.lemar/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
39.41.211.234 - - [29/Jul/2013:20:43:23 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/john.lemar/zest-project.zip HTTP/1.1" 200 632601 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/john.lemar/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
39.41.211.234 - - [29/Jul/2013:20:43:24 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/john.lemar/zest-project.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 285171 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/john.lemar/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
39.41.211.234 - - [29/Jul/2013:20:43:24 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/john.lemar/zest-project.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 138366 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/john.lemar/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
39.41.211.234 - - [29/Jul/2013:20:43:25 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/john.lemar/zest-project.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 104108 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/john.lemar/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
39.41.211.234 - - [29/Jul/2013:20:43:25 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/john.lemar/zest-project.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 52055 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/john.lemar/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
39.41.211.234 - - [29/Jul/2013:20:43:25 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/john.lemar/zest-project.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 63038 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/john.lemar/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
39.41.211.234 - - [29/Jul/2013:20:43:27 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/john.lemar/zest-project.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 32452 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/john.lemar/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
112.200.208.5 - - [29/Jul/2013:20:43:33 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/pos-code.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 215059 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
```

As I believe, the only valid download is this line is:

```
61.3.158.113 - - [29/Jul/2013:20:43:14 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/lnosKHEN/payroll_system_-_lnoskhen_0.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 10806 "http://www.mysite.com/download-code" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US)
```

Because I set all download to be coming from this URL:

```
http://www.mysite.com/download-code
```

So, how come the referrer seems to come from a folder?

Just like this line:

```
112.200.208.5 - - [29/Jul/2013:20:43:33 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/pos-code.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 215059 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
```

The refferer is:

```
http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/
```

This line:

```
/sites/default/files/download/argie/
```

is a folder.

Even if this is a web crawler, is it possible that it can access the folder on my site?

When I manually type the following:

```
http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/
```

It will simply return a "Page not found". That's why I'm wondering how it becomes the referrer.

BTW, I'm using nginx.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put too much attention on the referer. The referer can be set to anything by the client. It is just a header in the request.

For example

```
GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/pos-code.zip HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mysite.com
Referer: http://example.org/JUST/SOME/REFERRER
```

So I guess the crawler just cuts off the end of the path and sets it as a referrer. I wouldn't worry.

Comment: Some of the User-Agents look faked too.  Firefox 15.0.1 and Chrome 6 are both quite old.

Comment: Believe it or not but the crawler doesn't cut off the URL. That's the folder on some of the files in my server.

Comment: At lest in the logs you provided every referrer is the requested URL without the filename